# no www redirects to front page

Tags: redirection, .htaccess

I recently taken over a Drupal site to maintain and work on the design bit. I'm having an issue where if I enter a page on my site without the www prefix, I get directed to the front page. You should of course end up on the correct page anyway, maybe with the www prefix added.

I'm checking the .htaccess file and there i noticed this part:

```
 # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
 # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
 # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
 #
 # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
 # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
 # uncomment the following:
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 #
 # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
 # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
 # uncomment the following:
 # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
 # RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

As you can see I did comment out the first two rows so I thought this would correct this issue, but no, I get no change at all. Anyone got any idea about what could be wrong?

I also noticed this lines, which mentions a index.php redirect. But I can't really understand if this causes my problem.

```
 # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
 # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
 # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
 # RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

There seems to be no 404 page but every wrong adress get redirected to the front page.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this old method

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Replace example with your domain name.

Still if you have the problem check your Redirects in Hosting Control Panel or you can contact them to support this.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Turns out some kind of alias had to be turned on in the server settings. I didn't do it myself otherwise I would have posted the solution here.